# Change the plist before next version of my app - how to manage changes?

Tags: objective-c

My plist array of dictionaries is copied from the bundle to the documents directory if it doesn't already exist (appDidFinishLaunching).

Some of the strings in the dictionaries are user defined and have a default value before value is set by the user. (i.e. Key: "Favorite" value: "No" changes to "Yes" if added to favorites)

If I change some of the strings in some of the dictionaries (like if price of object changes) and/or add some new dictionaries to the array, how to manage those changes without changing the user defined strings?

I've thought about two options:

1: Compare strings in excisting dictionaries with the strings in the updated dictionaries and replace the changed ones without touching the user defined strings. Also look for new dictionaries.

2: Make a new plist of dictionaries for the user defined strings, with i.e. "Name" string equal the main object so they can be "connected" when the contents are displayed.. Then the main plist can be replaced and the user defined data remain untouched.

I think nr 2 would be the simplest way. But this is my first application so I don't know for sure..

So my question is: Is option 2 a good way? If yes, confirmation is accepted as answer. If no, I guess it's because you see some potential troubles, please explain and maybe suggest alternative ways if not nr 1.

Ps. current code for copy:

```
- (void)copyPlist {
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Objects.plist"];
     NSLog(@"Path %@", path); 

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Objects" ofType:@"plist"];

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:&error];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think option 2 would be your best option. Only let the user change the display names, not the internal names you use for the properties. Otherwise, what if you added another field, "Foo", at some point, but the user already had renamed the existing field "Bar" to be "Foo"?

Comment: Thanks, then I'll go for it. And make it "safe" for a case like your example. Will accept answer in 5 min... :)